# Сокеты в Qt, минимальные требования к их работе

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

Скажите, пожалуйста, обязательно ли создавать класс клиента для запуска сокета, имеется в виду QTcpSocket?

Т.е. можно ли вот так работать? Приложение консольное

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Prepare Connection";    
    QTcpSocket s;
    char Buf[16] = "First send";
    s.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 2025);
    s.write(Buf, 15);    
    qDebug() << "Connection was try";

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Можно, но в целом непонятно,  в чем вопрос?

Comment: Написал сервер под винду в дельфи, при помощи winsock. Аналогичный дельфи-клиент к нему коннектится нормально. Теперь требуется написать кроссплатформенного клиента (под линукс), выбор пал на Qt. Не могу подконнектиться к серверу через QtcpSocket. Вот решил сделать маленький клиент, чтоб разобраться, почему QtcpSocket не соединяется с winsock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "Prepare Connection";
    QTcpSocket s;
    char Buf[16] = "First send";
    s.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 2025);
    if(!s.waitForConnected())
    {
        qDebug() << "Can't connect to host";
    } else
    {
        s.write(Buf, 15);
        s.waitForBytesWritten();
        qDebug() << "Connection was try";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Нужно понимать что функции `connectToHost` и `write` асинхронные, для того чтоб дождаться их завершения, необходимо пользоваться функциями `waitForConnected` и `waitForBytesWritten`

Comment: функция waitForConnected  не дожидается коннекта к серверу. А дельфийский клиент подключается мгновенно. Вот почему не подключается, не пойму.

Comment: Что значит "не дожидается коннекта"? Функция ``waitForConnected `` возвращает false?

Comment: да, возвращает false.

Comment: Функция ``waitForConnected`` должна возвращать ``true`` при попытке подключения к любому TCP серверу, можно даже на ``google.com`` подключаться. Возможно неправильно указан порт для подключения или же на сервере какая-то "особенная" логика обработки входящих запросов.

Comment: может быт на winsock сервере нужно указывать какой-то особый тип протокола?

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена!
В дельфи порядок байтов программный и сетевой отличаются. На сервере при определении порта вызвал функцию htons(port) , и ... о чудо!!! клиент соединился с сервером.